# How to rewrite URL in .htaccess to another URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need help to rewrite this URL

```
https:///www.site.com/members/2257/
```

to this URL

```
https:///www.site.com/2257.html
```

and that this second one goes on the same page like the first one? Currently I have rule like this

```
RewriteRule ^members/2257/ 2257.html [NC,QSA,L]
```

and it shows this URL

```
https:///www.site.com/members/2257/
```

and 404 Not Found error with this message

```
The requested URL /members/2257/ was not found on this server.
```

In my a href I have like this

```
<p class="copyright">
    &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> Site All Rights Reserved. <a href="2257/" >18 U.S.C. 2257 Record-Keeping Requirements Compliance Statement</a>
</p>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use '/' in the RewriteRule like below

```
RewriteRule ^/members/2257/ /2257.html [NC,QSA,L]
```